# How can I go about implementing this screen design? Screen Compatibility required

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to implement the screen design that is shown below in my android app. I have come up with the design and it looks fine on my phone and devices greater than `480dp` in width. However I want to be able to produce similar results in smaller screens. I have tried using `layout-sw480dp` for this. What confuses me is, how I will be able to produce similar results without using hardcoded dimension values for the width and height of the `LinearLayout`s .

How I implemented the screen was I basically created Five `LinearLayout`s of fixed width and height values in `dp` and I used `ConstraintLayout` as root layout to create a `ConstraintGuide` (vertical) at 50% the screen size, then I constrained the first two `LinearLayout`s to left and right of that guideine.

I also used a `ConstraintGuide` (horizontal) at 60% of the screen and constrained the first two layouts above that guideline and the rest three below this guideline. I also constrained the three `Linearlayout`s in a horizontal chain style.

Another complexity is that the `TextView`s inside the `LinearLayout`s are not in single line. The first `TextView` is two lines long.

How would I go about implementing this screen design with screen compatibility in mind and also sticking close to the design.

[image: Required Screen Design]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!--- First pink half -->
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:background="#ff00ff"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1">
     </LinearLayout>

     <!--- Second half -->
     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1">

         <!--- Layout for 2 Buttons -->
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:background="#00ffff"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
                 <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button1"/>
                 <Button
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Button2"/>
             </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>

         <!--- Layout for 3 Buttons -->
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:background="#0000ff"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
                 <Button
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Button3"/>
                 <Button
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Button4"/>
                 <Button
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Button5"/>
             </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>

         <!--- Layout for round Button -->
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:background="#00ff00"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
             <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Round Button"/>
         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes something similar, but the Texts on the `Button`s are not same lengths. Some texts go 2 lines. Plus if the three buttons on the second half do not fit within the width, I think the height of the third `LinearLayout` increases, which is not the required functionality.

Comment: You could just design the button layout in a separate layout.xml file and add the clickable=true attribute. Than include the layout instead of the buttons into @K. Dexter 's answer.

Comment: Of course, the buttons should only be placeholders for your designed buttons, which (as Johannes mentioned), should be designed in an extra layout.

Comment: For designing the buttons in case of 2 lines: Are those 2 seperate strings for line 1 and line 2, or is that just 1 string and you used one  textview with multiline?